# How to create singleton for the WebSocket (Starscream)?

Tags: swift3, websocket, singleton, starscream

I am trying to create a singleton with WebSocket functionality and I just don't know why it's not working

This is my singleton extension:

```
import Starscream

extension WebSocketManager: WebSocketDelegate {
func websocketDidConnect(socket: WebSocket) {
    print("websocket is connected")
}

func websocketDidDisconnect(socket: WebSocket, error: NSError?) {
    if let e = error {
        print("websocket is disconnected: \(e.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        print("websocket disconnected")
    }
}

func websocketDidReceiveMessage(socket: WebSocket, text: String) {
    print("Received text: \(text)")
}

func websocketDidReceiveData(socket: WebSocket, data: Data) {
    print("Received data: \(data.count)")
}}
```

My singleton:

```
final class WebSocketManager: NSObject {
static let sharedInstance = WebSocketManager()
public var socket = WebSocket(url: URL(string: "ws://t-w-a.herokuapp.com/new")!)

private override init() {
    super.init()
    // testing connection of the socket
}

func establishConnection() {
    socket.connect()
}

func closeConnection() {
    socket.disconnect()
}}
```

When I am trying to connect the server just nothing happens. 
Here is my controller:

```
class ChatViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var typeText: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    WebSocketManager.sharedInstance.establishConnection()
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found problem, I just forgot to assign socket variable with the delegate

Comment: I just want to take the time to say thank you for finding the answer and updating this question.